# Angular testing with OnPush Component and fixture.detectChanges() - how to make the unit test reliable?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-test, angular-changedetection

In my [app](https://github.com/azerothcore/Keira3) I have a Component that simply gets some value async via some service and displays it to the user.

The code of the Component looks like the following:

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default,
  selector: 'test-component',
  template: `<div id="my-special-property">{{ myProperty }}</div>`,
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  private readonly someService = inject(SomeService);

  myProperty: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.someService.getSomeDataAsync().subscribe((value) => {
      this.myProperty = value;
    });
  }
}
```

and it is tested with a simple test that looks like this:

```
it('should correctly display myProperty in the HTML template of the Component', () => {
  const myMockedValue = 'Some mock value;'
  const { fixture, component, page } = setup();
  const someService = TestBed.inject(SomeService);
  spyOn(someService, 'getSomeDataAsync').and.returnValue(myMockedValue);

  fixture.detectChanges();

  expect(page.getMySpecialPropertyLocator().innerHTML).toContain(myMockedValue);
});
```

Everything works fine so far. Now, suppose that I want to change the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to `OnPush`. The Component will be broken because the change detection is not triggered after the value of `myProperty` has been updated:

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'test-component',
  template: `<div id="my-special-property">{{ myProperty }}</div>`,
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  private readonly someService = inject(SomeService);

  myProperty: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.someService.getSomeDataAsync().subscribe((value) => {
      this.myProperty = value;
    });
  }
}
```

Now, what is interesting is that **the test is still passing**. Because the change detection is triggered by that `fixture.detectChanges()`.

This is inconsistent: now my test is telling my that everything works fine, but in reality, it does not.

I know that to fix this bug, I simply have to manually call the change detection in my Component:

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'test-component',
  template: `<div id="my-special-property">{{ myProperty }}</div>`,
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  private readonly someService = inject(SomeService);
  private readonly changeDetectorRef = inject(ChangeDetectorRef);

  myProperty: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.someService.getSomeDataAsync().subscribe((value) => {
      this.myProperty = value;
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); // this fixes the problem
    });
  }
}
```

But with this fix, if I remove the `fixture.detectChanges()` from the test in the attempt to make it more realistic, it will fail:

```
it('should correctly display myProperty in the HTML template of the Component', () => {
  const myMockedValue = 'Some mock value;'
  const { fixture, component, page } = setup();
  const someService = TestBed.inject(SomeService);
  spyOn(someService, 'getSomeDataAsync').and.returnValue(myMockedValue);

  // this will fail
  expect(page.getMySpecialPropertyLocator().innerHTML).toContain(myMockedValue);
});
```

I found a way to make it realistic, meaning that the test would **pass** ONLY when the fix of `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` and it would **fail** when it is not there.

This way is calling `component.ngOnInit()` in the test manually, instead of `fixture.detectChanges()`, but I find it a bit ugly:

```
it('should correctly display myProperty in the HTML template of the Component', () => {
  const myMockedValue = 'Some mock value;'
  const { fixture, component, page } = setup();
  const someService = TestBed.inject(SomeService);
  spyOn(someService, 'getSomeDataAsync').and.returnValue(myMockedValue);

  component.ngOnInit();

  expect(page.getMySpecialPropertyLocator().innerHTML).toContain(myMockedValue);
});
```

what would be the proper way to achieve the same, without manually calling `component.ngOnInit()` from the unit test?

In other words, how to make sure that the unit test is **realistic** and it truly reflects the way the component behaves in the real application after `OnPush` change detection is used?

---

Note: this example is a simplified version of the real Component, which can be found here:

https://github.com/azerothcore/Keira3/tree/master/src/app/features/dashboard

Comment: you can make test with TestHostComponent which would render your real component and interact with it via inputs and outputs. this way you can reliably check change detection

Answer (score 1):

Usually when dealing with `OnPush` you should use a more reactive approach.

The key is to use the `AsyncPipe`.

Simply, there are two possible way

1. You are using state management

   When you subscribe to the HTTP observable call, simply update the state. In your template, you will subscribe trough the `AsyncPipe` to the state property observable.
2. You are not using state management

   You can assign (without the `.subscribe`) the method call (`SomeService#getSomeDataAsync`) to a class property `myProperty$`. Note that, if you do not cache, each time Change Detection is triggered, an http call will be triggered. Just call `pipe` over `myProperty$` and ensure you are caching the observable with `share` or `shareReplay` operators.

In general, the `OnPush` + `AsyncPipe` is a valid friend. Give it a try!

Comment: what you are saying is indeed correct and the best solution, but it requires refactoring the existing code. I was just wondering if there was a solution with the current code. Not because I don't want to refactor, but because I wanted to better understand the mechanism of `fixture.detectChanges()` in unit tests done with OnPush.

Comment: I see.. sometimes, refactoring is not possible.. I will give a look at the docs and if I find something I will let you know